# Mobiscroll, identify element triggering it

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobiscroll

**Scenario:**

I've got a form which needs multiple time and select pickers, In order to reduce duplications I came up with the plan of having only 2 hidden inputs one for time and the other for the select picker, then I have multiple links/buttons with the class of for e.g. "triggerTime"

HTML:

```
<input class="hidden" id="timeSelect" />

<button class="triggerTime" id="btn1">Select time 1</button>
<button class="triggerTime" id="btn2">Select time 2</button>
<button class="triggerTime" id="btn3">Select time 3</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
//triggering time picker
$('.triggerTime').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#timeSelect').mobiscroll('show');
    //$('#timeSelect').mobiscroll('trigger', name, $.makeArray(e));
});

//activating time picker
$('#timeSelect').mobiscroll().time({
    theme: 'ios7',
    display: 'bottom',
    mode: 'scroller',
    headerText: false,
    onSelect: function(valueText,inst) {
        console.log('onSelect',valueText,inst,this);
    },
    onShow: function(html, valueText, inst) {
        console.log('onShow',html,valueText,inst);
    },
    onBeforeShow: function (html, inst) {
    console.log('onBeforeShow',html,inst,this);
    }
});
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to pass on the information of the element triggering the mobiscroll during "onSelect"? I need to know which button triggered the mobiscroll

Component versions:

- Mobiscroll 2.8.2
- Jquery 2.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way I could achieve what I wanted (no additional activation needed)

```
$('.triggerTime').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    var clickedElement = $(this);
    $('#timeSelect').mobiscroll({
            anchor: clickedElement,
            theme: 'ios7',
            display: 'bottom',
            mode: 'scroller',
            headerText: false,
            preset: 'time',
            onSelect: function (valueText,inst) {
                    clickedElement.html(valueText);
            }
    });
    $('#timeSelect').mobiscroll('show');
});
```